# What is the purpose of this js code?

Tags: javascript

Could it be used to increase the number of tree planted of ecosia.com homepage?

```
const TotalTreecountComponent = View.extend({
    initialize(data) {
        const model = new TotalTreecountModel(data);
        const view = new TotalTreecountView({
            model,
            el: '.js-total-tree-count-wrapper'
        });
        this.setElement(view.render().el);

        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            model.increment();
        }, 2000);

        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            model.increment();
        }, data.secondsToPlantTree * 1000);
    },
    remove() {
        View.prototype.remove.call(this);
        window.clearInterval(this.interval);
        window.clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    }
});
```

I am a beginner in js so be cool :D

Comment: Can it be used for that? Try it and you'll know the answer. But I suspect that's not your actual question.

Comment: What do you mean ? This is my question, I try to understand how this work. How could I try it ? I just copy-paste some code I found on a website sources and require help to understand it. I don't get the 6 downvote. Can you explain me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout()` only run once after certain time period (2s here (2000ms)).

`setInterval()` will loop forever until stoped by `window.clearInterval()`

your code here the timeout will have a delay for 2s then call `model.increment();`

your code for setInterval will repeat the sec you set at `data.secondsToPlantTree`

ref:

> **Window setTimeout() Method**
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp
>
> **Window setInterval() Method**
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp